# javascript Console.log prints only initial integer part of the list value instead of full value. See code for more details

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console

I have alphanumeric value in the list to be printed but console.log prints only the initial integer part of it instead of the complete value. Here is the html section.

```
<div class="folder-menu" id="folder-list">
<ul>
    <li value="100000685a35ba54b87d4e16952b3e196b1219c7"><a href="#">testing<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li value="100000689438bffac5934f97be1b15d7f5147e39"><a href="#">test1<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li value="10000068d412927da1cb4d42afba45c53f415c0e"><a href="#">test<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li value="10000068f141dbc2945347b0a71b2eddbbeda914"><a href="#">teasf<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>                
</ul>
```

And here is the javascript

```
$("#folder-list ul li a").click(function(event){
    console.log("this is the value "+$(this).parent().attr('value'));
    console.log("this is the value "+$(this).parent().val());
});
```

After i click say first element in list, it prints

this is the value 100000685 // instead of 100000685a35ba54b87d4e16952b3e196b1219c7

this is the value 100000685 // instead of 100000685a35ba54b87d4e16952b3e196b1219c7

Can someone say what is wrong with this code?

Comment: technically you should be using `data-value="100000685a35ba54b87d4e16952b3e196b1219c7"` and use `$(this).parent().data("value")`

Comment: @epascarello although he'd probably continue to have the same problem. It looks to me as if jQuery is attempting to "recognize" the value; I though it only did  that via `.data()` however

Comment: [I don't see that behavior.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/gX4sX/) What browser are you using?

Comment: @Pointy the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html#li) says li's value is an integer so data-value would work.

Comment: @epascarello yes I hadn't thought about that until I read Guffa's answer. The jQuery auto-interpretation feature for `.data()` confuses me, though it's helpful at times.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML code is invalid, so the browser tries its best to try to correct it. The `value` attribute of an `li` element should be a numeric value.

The specific browser that you are using have been designed to use the part of the attribute that can be interpreted as a number, so it will truncate the value where the digits end. Different browsers will handle this in different ways. Firefox for example will return the original value when you use `attr('value')` and the truncated value when using `val()`.

You can't reliably store anything other than numbers in the `value` attribute of the `li` element. To store an alphanumeric value you should put it somewhere else. You can for example use the `class` attribute, or a `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To use `data` attribute to achieve your goal. The `value` attribute in `li` tag should be in 
`Number`.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9GXkg/2/)**

```
<div class="folder-menu" id="folder-list">
<ul>
    <li data-val="100000685a35ba54b87d4e16952b3e196b1219c7"><a href="#">testing<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li data-val="100000689438bffac5934f97be1b15d7f5147e39"><a href="#">test1<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li data-val="10000068d412927da1cb4d42afba45c53f415c0e"><a href="#">test<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>
    <li data-val="10000068f141dbc2945347b0a71b2eddbbeda914"><a href="#">teasf<span class="folder-menu-count">0</span></a></li>                
</ul>

$("#folder-list ul li a").click(function(event){
    console.log("this is the value1 "+$(this).parent().attr('data-val'));
    console.log("this is the value2 "+$(this).parent().data('val'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Guffa said the reason of this issue , but you can change the value markup to anything that you want eg value2 and get the value by this code

```
console.log("this is the value "+$(this).parent().attr('value2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In `li` tag, as `value` you can use "correctly" only number.

See this syntax example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp

But, you can do something else as use other atribute for store your value. There is a way how to extract full value using jQuery. I think you use jQuery 1.8 (on this version I get the same results). Please, try check you example with useing jQuery 1.9.x (I try it in Chrome and Internet Explorer and it work fine)

Look for my example with jQuery 1.9.1. You can see it here:
[Version with jQuery **1.9.1**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mftn/1/)
[Your version with jQuery **1.8.3**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mftn/2/)

With this configuration (jQuery 1.9.1) you can use your original call:

```
$(this).parent().attr('value')
```

to get correct result.